# добавить iostream в исходники

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, компиляция

Нужно, чтобы при работе одной из функций кода postgre данные записывались в файл. Для этого решил добавить `iostream` в код. Попробовал просто приписать (попробовал оба варианта):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На этапе make выдал ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал явно прописать `#include "/usr/iostream.h"`, предварительно скачав этот файл и добавив в usr,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
выдает такие ошибки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что делать?

Comment: На ответ вас должны натолкнуть расширения файлов исходных кодов PostgreSQL. Он написан на C, а не на C++. Если уж хотите добавить таким образом дополнительный вывод, что плохая идея, то придётся использовать функции из stdio.h.

Comment: stdio.h удастся добавить инклюдом?

Comment: А можно текст в виде текста?

Answer (score 0):

C и C++ - это всё же разные языки. Тем не менее PostgreSQL поддерживает сборку компилятором для C++, но вы судя по всему используете компилятор C, которому синтаксис из C++ конечно не известен.

С точки зрения стандартов кодирования postgresql правильным для работы с файлами будет использовать функции из `src/include/storage/fd.h` которые в `md.c` уже и используется для операций.